# Form submit (email) with ASP.net and jQuery not working

Tags: asp.net, jquery, email

I'm trying to figure this out, but I'm not having much luck.

Basically, I have a wizard style HTML form that's built using the jQuery form wizard plugin, which includes the jQuery.Form, jQuery.Validation and jQuery.History plugins. I'm trying to use ASP.net Web Forms to submit an email, but I can't seem to make it work at all.

here's an example of my markup and code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="step" id="step01">
        <input type="text" id="text1" name="text1" runat="server" /><br />
        <input type="text" id="text2" name="text2" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="step" id="step02">
        <input type="text" id="text3" name="text3" runat="server" /><br />
        <input type="text" id="text4" name="text4" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <input type="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" id="submit" Text="Submit" OnClick="button_Click" />
</form>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

public partial class email_test02 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //create the mail message
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        //set the addresses
        mail.From = new MailAddress("test@test.com");
        mail.To.Add("test2@test.com");

        //set the content
        mail.Subject = "Test";
        mail.Body =
            text1.Value + text2.Value + text3.Value + text4.Value;

        //send the message
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("Localhost");
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I need to do from here. I'm still pretty new to jQuery and very new to ASP.net, so I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious, but I've had no luck with anything I've tried. So if someone could point me in the right direction here it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't include any jQuery, so I'm confused as to what the problem is. Does the jQuery not run? Does the button click server code not run?

Comment: Please be more specific as to the nature of the problem. Are you getting an error message after clicking the button? Is the email getting sent?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to word my question. Basically, my first problem is that I don't know how to send email with Jquery AJAX and ASP.net using the JQuery form plugin, and my second problem will be making that work with the jQuery Form Wizard plugin i mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery form for the submittion remove the onclick and give the form an id.
The ID goes into your javascript code on the page to collect your post.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#form1').ajaxForm(function() { 
            location.href=("submitted.aspx");
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

in your page load simply add

```
if(isPostback){
    string txt1 = Request["text1"];

    // you will want to clean this string, (encode for storage) 
    // and maybe also check for isnull or empty first i.e

    var username = !string.IsNullorEmpty(Request["text1"]) ? Request["text1"] : null;

}
```